# C++: Cast const reference of Base class to derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to get my Base class instance and cast it to the derived class type. Since I can only get a const reference of my base class instance, I struggle to get it cast correctly. Does anyone have an idea?

```
class Base
{

};

class Derived : public Base
{

};

Base someBaseInstance;
const Base& GetBase()
{
    return someBaseInstance;
}

int main()
{

    Derived& derived = static_cast<Base&>(GetBase());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't make a base a derived.  There is no info on how to complete the derived part of the object.

Comment: If your `Base` instance is not a `Derived` why are you trying to cast it to a `Derived`? This sounds like an XY problem. Why you need to do this?

Comment: A cast that compiles would be `const Derived& derived = static_cast<const Derived&>(GetBase());` but it just produces undefined behavior. You can also cast away `const` but that just makes it even worse.

Comment: Ah sheeit, yeah ... you are right ... Then I have to change the way it's working. I wanted to derive from a given class (not created by me) and add some methods to it. But now I have to make my class take a reference of an instance of the class I want to enhance...

Answer (score -1):

You must declare your instance as a `Derived` object. It can be referenced and passed as it's `Base`, but must be declared as `Derived`:

```
Derived someDerivedInstance;
```

Also, to convert between `Base` and `Derived`, you should use `dynamic_cast<>`:

```
Derived &derived = dynamic_cast<Derived&>(GetBase());
```

Comment: I get this error with your solution: cannot dynamic_cast 'GetBase()' (of type 'const class Base') to type 'class Derived&' (conversion casts away constness)

Comment: casting to const Dervied& gives me this error: cannot dynamic_cast 'GetBase()' (of type 'const class Base') to type 'const class Derived&' (source type is not polymorphic)